# Override a theme template variable with a module

Tags: 8

I created two variables for use in my theme's page templates. I used variables because I wanted that value to be flexible.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['var1'] = 'value1';
  $variables['var2'] = 'value2';
}
```

Without creating a new `page.html.twig` template, I want to choose new variables in `mymodule`. Like, maybe...

```
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['var1'] = 'newvalue1';
  $variables['var2'] = 'newvalue2';
}
```

This isn't working. I have a feeling it's because themes get priority? Any ideas?

Edit: I should clarify. How do I do this?

Comment: Themes do get priority as it is the last in line.

Comment: How can I make the module take priority in this case?

Comment: What's the point in having those lines in the theme, if the module takes precedence? Why not remove them? (If they supply a default, you could check whether there's already a value rather than setting unconditionally).

Comment: Most of our sites built on this platform using a basetheme/sub-theme will need the same values. But from time to time we'll need a one-off site that has a custom module to do this and other site-specific things. 

So all of our sites will share the default values, but sometimes we'll need to override them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the lead from @Alfred Armstrong above and my colleague, this ended up working!

In `mytheme.theme`

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if(!isset($variables['var1'])) {
    $variables['var1'] = 'defaultvalue1';
  }
}
```

In `mymodule.module`

```
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['var1'] = 'myvalue1';
}
```

Comment: In php 7 you can do this in one line using the null coalescing operator "??". Try $variables['var1'] = $variables['var1'] ?? 'default';